# Qt: How To Build QMYSQL Plugin

Tags: c++, qt

I've got some issue here. My code is as usual:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
```

When I want to connect to my DB, it says:

"QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded,
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC QPSQL"

When I check "C:\Qt\6.2.2\mingw_64\plugins\sqldrivers", here's what I found.

[image]

What should I do to build the plugin?

I did like this C:\Qt\6.2.2\mingw_64\plugins\sqldrivers>qmake -- MYSQL_INCDIR="somepath/include" MYSQL_LIBDIR="somepath/lib", don't mind the somepath, mine's long so I just make it short here. But it just gives me [image]

Comment: You probably have to compile Qt with mysql support and so mysql library installed too. q*sql.dll is just an interface to a specified DB. See [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html) link for more info

Comment: Let me rephrase my question. How do you build it exactly?

Comment: Check the link I've provided

Comment: Yeah, I've read [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#how-to-build-the-qmysql-plugin-on-windows) but still don't get it.

Comment: Start doing what the instructions tell you and show your output and concerns. I don't see how it would help if we just repeated the instructions.

Comment: The Qt6 instructions are here: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/sql-driver.html#how-to-build-the-qmysql-plugin-on-windows](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/sql-driver.html#how-to-build-the-qmysql-plugin-on-windows)

Comment: For this command `qt-cmake -G Ninja <qt_installation_path>\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=<qt_installation_path>\<platform> -DMySQL_INCLUDE_DIR="C:\mysql-8.0.22-winx64\include" -DMySQL_LIBRARY="C:\mysql-8.0.22-winx64\lib\libmysql.lib"` you have to figure out the folder where Qt in are and replace `<qt_installation_path>` with the path to that folder.

Comment: Qt6 has slightly different instructions from Qt5. The original link was the Qt5 instructions.

Comment: I wanna ask, where do you find path like this "C:\Qt\6.0.0\Src\qtbase\src\plugins\sqldrivers"

Comment: From almost all the things I've searched, they used paths like that. But I don't see it anywhere in my device.

Comment: Where is your Qt6 installed? You may have to go back to the online installer and have it install the source code for Qt

Comment: Just at C:\Qt directory

Comment: In the online installer Sources is an option for each version of Qt you install. You can go back and add the sources.

Comment: Alright, done installing that Sources. But where do I enter that command? And also what does that <platform> mean? Windows or something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241343/discussion-between-riiko-and-drescherjm).